# Search Engine results from different locations

Tags: google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differences between google domains in different countries](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/differences-between-google-domains-in-different-countries)

We are getting different results for the same search words at different countries.

How can i get the google results for the same key words as if am in different countries..

in other words,

```
            how can i get different country google results??
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Google URL local to those countries? e.g. ww.google.com.au for Australia.

Comment: If you are getting redirected to you local top level domain when entering a different country's URL, you can simply append `/ncr` to the URL, which stands for "no country redirect", e. g. http://www.google.it/ncr will give you the Italian Google page.

Comment: It is doubtful that this will actually give geo-targeted results, though, and not only the local search page.

Comment: It wouldn't really make sense for Google not to give you geo-targeted results for that country though. Otherwise, there'd be no way for someone on vacation in a different country to get search results for their country. There'd also be no point in giving internet users multiple Google domains to access. After all, if a user goes to `google.it`, then it's pretty obvious they want to search mainly for Italian content regardless of where they are physically.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to simulate this, especially seeing as search results are often local not only to the country, but to the region or city as well.

I think professional SEO companies use proxied internet connections to get local search results.

Comment: Do you have any sources for the claim that Google results are geotargeted to cities? Because I frequently share SERP links with people in other parts of the U.S., and they always seem to see the same results as I do.

Comment: @Lèse they definitely do, at least here in Germany. I get local results all the time when I enter e.g. "Carpenter" or "Cinema" or the name of a well-known movie: http://i.imgur.com/SJ7BF.png However, admittedly, those are always clearly marked as local results, they do not get mixed in with the search results.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant the entire SERP is geotargeted to your city. Yea, I suppose those results would not be available if you're searching Google.de from overseas. Though I remember Google/ig allowing you to select a home location. I wonder if it would use that to provide local results for when you're accessing the search from outside the country.